# Accessing Spring Rest with 404 error

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring MVC in my project and while mapping user request to a URI, I get the 404 error. But there are other controllers where i'm able to access it.

**Working controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "groupview.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showGroups(
            @ModelAttribute("groupRegistrationDTO") GroupRegistrationDTO groupRegistrationDTO,
            BindingResult result, Model model,
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {

GroupsResultDTO groupsResultDTO = manageGroupBusiness.getGroups(
                groupRegistrationDTO, result, model);


return "showGroups";
}
```

**Testing with java class showing desired output**

```
private static void wsRequest(String jsonInput) {
        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://localhost:5080/myservlet/groupview.htm");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "
                    + getBasicAuthenticationEncoding());

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (conn.getInputStream())));

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }

            conn.disconnect();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
```

Now i have another controller which is a restful service when i try to test that using poster plugin or through java net URL connection(using requestmethod post). I get 404 response code.

Trying to access with URL :

```
http://localhost:5080/myservlet/authAndRegDevice.htm
```

**Rest Service Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "authAndRegDevice.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String authenticateAndRegisterDevice(
        @RequestBody String notificationJsonRequest){

return "success";
}
```

Why would the second controller give the 404 error while the first one working.
Can some one please help me to get out of this issue

Comment: Are you sending a Json as Request Body for the second call when you invoke http://localhost:5080/myservlet/authAndRegDevice.htm? and ; at the end is that accidental or you invoke the same url?

Comment: Have you registered the bean controller for the second method?

Comment: @shazin : yes i'm sending json input as request body i dint get the second question regarding the same url

Comment: http://localhost:5080/myservlet/authAndRegDevice.htm; at the end you have a ';' is this required or accidental?

Comment: no that was kept accidentally in the post. updated in my original post

Comment: Ok Please show the complete Exception stack trace and your code to call the authAndRegDevice.htm post

Comment: @shazin There is no strack trace w.r.t service... while trying to consume a service(authAndRegDevice.htm) through a java main class method wsRequest(available in my original post)... i get the 404 response code. But when i consume other service(groupview.htm) i'm getting the response as expected. This service is also in the same web application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bypass spring security with java URL connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800657/bypass-spring-security-with-java-url-connection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be closed here as i have raised another post with detailed question and with the exact failure where i was facing.

[Bypass spring security with java URL connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800657/bypass-spring-security-with-java-url-connection)