# Bypass spring security with java URL connection

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring MVC in my project and while mapping user request to a URI, I was unable to bypass it. I get the 403 error as the url is intercepted. But i was able to access it through browser.

*Updated*

> I removed the interception in security.xml and when i try to hit i get the following error.
>
> **Request method 'POST' not supported**

```
http://49.205.88.200:5080/Batasariservice/groupview.htm
username :  userx@bat
password :  123456
```

*Updated:*

**My Rest Controller:**

```
 @RestController
public class AuthenticateDeviceRestWS {

    @Autowired
    ManageDeviceWSBusiness manageDeviceWSBusiness;

    @RequestMapping(value = "authAndRegDevice.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String authenticateAndRegisterDevice(
            @RequestBody String notificationJsonRequest)
            throws BatasariWSException {
        WSDeviceAuthenticateRequest wsDeviceAuthenticateRequest = (WSDeviceAuthenticateRequest) UserAccessManagementUtil
                .convertToJava(notificationJsonRequest,
                        WSDeviceAuthenticateRequest.class);

        WSDeviceAuthenticateResponse wsDeviceAuthenticateResponse = manageDeviceWSBusiness
                .authAndRegisterDevice(wsDeviceAuthenticateRequest);

        return UserAccessManagementUtil
                .convertToJson(wsDeviceAuthenticateResponse);
    }

}
```

*Updated*
Java Main class i.e., tested with

```
public class AuthURLConnection {
static String URL = "http://localhost:5080/Batasariservice/authAndRegDevice.htm";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String json = "{ " + "\"deviceID\":\"Test\", "
            + "\"deviceName\":\"Test Device\",  "
            + "\"phoneNumber\":\"testnumber\",   "
            + "\"companyIdentifier\":\"bat\",   "
            + "\"userIdentifier\":\"Test\",   " + "\"addtionalInfo\":\"\""
            + "}";
    wsRequest(json);

}

private static void wsRequest(String jsonInput) {

    try {

        URL targetUrl = new URL(URL);
        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) targetUrl
                .openConnection();

        httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/json");



        OutputStream outputStream = httpConnection.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(jsonInput.getBytes());
        outputStream.flush();

        if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + httpConnection.getResponseCode() + ":"
                    + httpConnection.getResponseMessage());
        }

        BufferedReader responseBuffer = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(httpConnection.getInputStream()));

        String output;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while ((output = responseBuffer.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(output);
        }

        httpConnection.disconnect();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

}

*Updated*
my spring-security.xml file

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/userLogin*" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/authAndRegDevice.htm" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('DefaultRole')" />

        <!-- access denied page -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

        <form-login login-page="/userLogin.htm" default-target-url="/groupview.htm"
            authentication-failure-url="/userLogin.htm?error" username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" authentication-success-handler-ref="authSuccessHandler" />

        <csrf />
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="authSuccessHandler"
        class="com.pathfinder.filter.AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl" />
    <beans:bean id="encoder"
        class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>


        <authentication-manager>
            <authentication-provider>
                <password-encoder ref="encoder" />
                <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                    users-by-username-query="select username,password, status from users where username=?"
                    authorities-by-username-query="select username, 'DefaultRole' as role from userrolesview where username =?  " />
            </authentication-provider>
        </authentication-manager>
```

Comment: in browser, password was never requested ?

Comment: Strange!!! I'm getting a login screen. After login it is showing a table with one item in it. @coder what is it that is showing when you hit the URL??

Comment: so it means authentication is working ?

Comment: yes authentication is working in browser... But when i'm trying to consume that servlet/service from a java main class... i'm unable to bypass the security intercept

Comment: Even though the request mapping is POST i get the error Request method 'POST' not supported

Comment: If it works in a browser and not from your java class use a spy such as the excellent [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) (exists on many systems) and look what happens in both. You will at least know what the problem is and if you cannot fix it you will be able to post a more understandable (and answerable) question.

Comment: Sorry my bad!!! It is not working even in the browser... I gave up created a new project removing security.. And now i'm able to access through browser and also through java